# Confusion between prediction matrix and measurement covariance matrix in Kalman filter

Tags: matlab, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement Kalman filter for vehicle tracking in MATLAB. A Vehicle is moving in X direction with constant velocity. Initial state for vehicle =[x(t) v(t)].

I have to find position of vehicle after t=2 sec. Position of vehicle from GPS is corrupted by noise.

My question is: if I consider that there is no process noise, then will initial prediction matrix be equal to measurement noise matrix? I don't know how to initialise prediction matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any part of your state that is initialized from a measurement can have the corresponding variance initialized from the measurement variance.  If your state has other variables (e.g. velocity) which aren't directly measured, then you'll have to put in educated guesses about how far wrong you could be.  Variance has units of "state unit squared" (because variance is the square of standard deviation).  So if your velocity estimate has a 68% chance (see: normal distribution) of being within +/-7mph, then the initial variance would be 49 miles^2/hour^2.

Comment: A vehicle is moving in X direction with velocity 10m/sec. The vehicle is at position X=5 at t=0. Therefore, initial state at time t=0: x(t)=[5;10].  Standard deviation in the position of vehicle by GPS is lets say 10.                Therefore, R=10^2. Process noise=0, and prediction matrix,P=[10 0; 0 10]. I have considered the above situation. please correct me if i am wrong anywhere.

Comment: Process noise ("Q") is only 0 if you know the car is truly constant velocity.  If it is accelerating or decelerating, Q should reflect your prediction error.  The matrix "P" is the error covariance matrix.  So far, P=[R 0; 0 ?].  The ? is related to how good your guess of 10m/sec is.

Comment: :If i consider that  velocity measurement are not taken from GPS and they have no error, then what will come in place of '?'. I am not able to understand meaning of 'how good your guess of 10m/sec is'.  I hope u

Comment: "Have no error" means `? = 0`, but it's not likely that it truly has *no* error.  If it truly has no initial error and no ongoing error (same term in Q is also 0) then you don't need to model it in your state at all.

Comment: Ok. if velocity measurement are taken from GPS, then it will have error. I think error covariance matrix P= [R 0; 0 R]. Am i correct? GPS measures velocity of a vehicle by calculating change in position per unit time.

Comment: Your last question is more about how GPS works than how a KF works.  If velocity is truly a first-order difference (`x[1] - x[0]`) then the error of the difference in position is `2R * (1/dt)^2`